# How do I find pairs that share the one property (column) through multiple tuples (rows)?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to find pairs of users that enjoy the same set of TV shows in this simplified example

Let's say I have a table where each user gets an entry for each TV Show that they enjoy:

```
|USER | Show        |
|-----|-------------|
|001  | Lost        |
|001  | South Park  |
|002  | Lost        |
|003  | Lost        |
|003  | South Park  |
|004  | South Park  |
|005  | Lost        |
|006  | Lost        |
```

Then I would like a result of:

```
|USER1 |USER2 |
|------|------|
|001   |003   |
|003   |001   |
|002   |005   |
|002   |006   |
|005   |002   |
|005   |006   |
|006   |002   |
|006   |005   |
```

Or an even better version would be:

```
|USER1 |USER2 |
|------|------|
|001   |003   |
|002   |005   |
|002   |006   |
|005   |006   |
```

Which basically says: User 1 likes the same set of shows as User 3.

I've been playing around with GROUP BY and JOIN, but I still can't find the answer :(.

So far, I've found that using

```
SELECT s1.User as USER1, s2.User as USER2, s1.Show as Show 
FROM Shows s1 JOIN (SELECT * FROM Shows) s2 
ON s1.Shows=s2.Shows AND s1.User!=s2.User;
```

Which yields pairs of users and the Show they have in common. But I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Show us what you have been playing around with.

Comment: I think the expected result doesn't match the provided sample data. In the sample data you have 6 users but only two TV shows and in the expected result it is vice versa.

Comment: SELECT s1.User as USER1, s2.User as USER2, s1.Show as Show
FROM Shows s1
JOIN (SELECT *
   FROM Shows) s2
ON s1.Shows=s2.Shows AND s1.User!=s2.User;


This yields a list of pairs that like at least one same TV show.

@DanielHilgarth I want to find pairs of users that watch ALL the same TV Shows. User 1 and User 3 both watch Lost and South Park. User 2 and User 5 both watch Lost. User 2 and User 6 both watch Lost. etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can accept CSV instead of tabulated results, you could simply group the table twice:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(User) FROM (
  SELECT   User, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `Show` ORDER BY `Show` SEPARATOR 0x1e) AS s
  FROM     Shows
  GROUP BY User
) t GROUP BY s
```

Otherwise, you can join the above subquery to itself:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEAST(t.User, u.User) AS User1,
             GREATEST(t.User, u.User) AS User2
FROM (
  SELECT   User, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `Show` ORDER BY `Show` SEPARATOR 0x1e) AS s
  FROM     Shows
  GROUP BY User
) t JOIN (
  SELECT   User, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `Show` ORDER BY `Show` SEPARATOR 0x1e) AS s
  FROM     Shows
  GROUP BY User
) u USING (s)
WHERE t.User <> u.User
```

See them on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8ef53/2).

Of course, if duplicate `(User, Show)` pairs are *guaranteed* not to exist in the `Shows` table, you could improve performance by removing the `DISTINCT` keyword from the `GROUP_CONCAT()` aggregations.

Comment: Just tried this and it worked great! Thanks! I didn't know things like GROUP_CONCAT even existed.

Comment: @HeartAce, I've added another answer for your amusement.

Answer (score 0):

After thinking on this more I wondered, what if I grouped the groups,

```
select
    group_concat( 
      User
      order by User
      separator ', '
      ) LikeViewers
  , Shows
from
(
select
      User
    , group_concat(
        concat('"', Show, '"')
        order by Show
        separator ', '
        ) Shows
  from
    Viewings
  group by
    User
) ViewerGroups
group by
  Shows
```

which produces a output like this

```
|LikeViewers  |Shows               |
|-------------|--------------------|
|002, 005, 006|"Lost"              |
|001, 003     |"Lost", "South Park"|
|004          |"South Park"        |
```

admittedly, the results could be more reuseable but I thought it was an interesting idea.

[Fiddle Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c105/23)